# Unpivot multiple columns showing incorrect results

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

My initial query and result looks like below

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT S.CURRENCYCD , S.COMBINEDTXNAMOUNT
      , S.INTERCHANGEAMOUNT
      , S.OTHERCHARGEAMOUNT
     ,S.APPLIEDCHARGES
      FROM 
      (SELECT X.CURRENCYCD,
             CASE WHEN X.CombinedTxnAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.CombinedTxnAmount END AS CombinedTxnAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.InterchangeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.InterchangeAmount END AS InterchangeAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.OtherChargeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.OtherChargeAmount END AS OtherChargeAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount END +
             CASE WHEN X.AppliedChargeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.AppliedChargeAmount END AS APPLIEDCHARGES FROM 
     XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.eds.com/AgileCard/xsd/ACFMerchantStatement/2013/05' AS "acf",'http://www.eds.com/AgileCard/xsd/ACFMerchant/2012/03' as "acfMerchant")
 ,'/acf:Statement/acf:ChargeSummaryTotals/acf:ChargeSummaryTotalDetail' passing xmltype ('Myxml')
  COLUMNS CURRENCYCD VARCHAR(4) PATH 'acfMerchant:CurrencyCd',
          CombinedTxnAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:CombinedTxnAmount',
          InterchangeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:InterchangeAmount',
          OtherChargeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:OtherChargeAmount',
          MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount',
          AppliedChargeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:AppliedChargeAmount'
 )X ) S
```

The result is:

```
currencyCD | combinedTxnAmount | InterchangeAmount| OtherChangeAmount|AppliedCharges

GBP | 126.5 | 97.02 | 252.92 | 476.44
```

I am trying to unpivot this query result but for some reason I am not getting the expected result. Below is my unpivot query.

```
 SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT S.CURRENCYCD , S.COMBINEDTXNAMOUNT
      , S.INTERCHANGEAMOUNT
      , S.OTHERCHARGEAMOUNT
     ,S.APPLIEDCHARGES
      FROM 
      (SELECT X.CURRENCYCD,
             CASE WHEN X.CombinedTxnAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.CombinedTxnAmount END AS CombinedTxnAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.InterchangeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.InterchangeAmount END AS InterchangeAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.OtherChargeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.OtherChargeAmount END AS OtherChargeAmount,
             CASE WHEN X.MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount END +
             CASE WHEN X.AppliedChargeAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.AppliedChargeAmount END AS APPLIEDCHARGES FROM 
     XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.eds.com/AgileCard/xsd/ACFMerchantStatement/2013/05' AS "acf",'http://www.eds.com/AgileCard/xsd/ACFMerchant/2012/03' as "acfMerchant")
 ,'/acf:Statement/acf:ChargeSummaryTotals/acf:ChargeSummaryTotalDetail' passing xmltype ('myxml')
  COLUMNS CURRENCYCD VARCHAR(4) PATH 'acfMerchant:CurrencyCd',
          CombinedTxnAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:CombinedTxnAmount',
          InterchangeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:InterchangeAmount',
          OtherChargeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:OtherChargeAmount',
          MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:MinimumBillAdjustmentAmount',
          AppliedChargeAmount NUMBER PATH 'acf:AppliedChargeAmount'
 )X ) S) UNPIVOT ((AMT) FOR TASK IN ((COMBINEDTXNAMOUNT) AS 'Combined Transaction Charge',
                                     (INTERCHANGEAMOUNT) as 'Interchange'     
                                   ,(OTHERCHARGEAMOUNT) as 'Other Charges'
                                   ,(APPLIEDCHARGES) as 'Charges Applied To Account'
                                   ))
```

Below is what this query returns:

```
currencycd |      Task                   | AMT  
GBP        | Combined Transaction Charge | 126.5  
GBP        | Interchange                 | 0  
GBP        | Other Charges               | 0  
GBP        | Charges Applied To Account  | 0
```

Only the first unpivot value displays the amount correctly. Remaining values are displayed as zero.

Can someone point me what is going wrong with this query.

Comment: The query seems OK, check your source data. Also, you have `xmltype ('Myxml')` in the first query and `xmltype ('myxml')` in the second. Also, use `nvl(X.CombinedTxnAmount, 0)` instead of `CASE WHEN X.CombinedTxnAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X.CombinedTxnAmount END`.

Comment: I did not mention the xml as it is sensitive data. As I shown in my first query, my xml reading is giving the query output correctly.

Comment: Nevertheless I took your second query and replaced the inner subquery with my own data. The query works fine, which means the problem is inside, between `SELECT S.CURRENCYCD , S.COMBINEDTXNAMOUNT ...` and `...  )X ) S`.

Comment: Looks like it is a known bug in Oracle.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533111800346252295      . I am not sure whether this bug is already fixed or not.

Comment: A temporary solution using UNION ALL works much better. I added the below part in my inner query and it works as expected.     "UNION ALL (select '1' as CURRENCYCD,
                       1 as COMBINEDTXNAMOUNT,
                       1 as INTERCHANGEAMOUNT,
                       1 AS OTHERCHARGEAMOUNT,
                       1 AS APPLIEDCHARGES
                  from dual where 1=2)"